# How to replace text of a cell based on condition in excel

Tags: excel

I have the following data which is sorted as:

| Activity_ID | Employee Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| B | 8 |
| C | 4 |

This is suppose to be top 10 sorting; I want to replace the last Activity value ( C ) with "other" word instead of the original value.  Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to replace the `Activity_ID` "C" with another word or `Employee Count` of 4 with another word?  Are you specifically looking to replace `Activity_ID` "C", or the last activity in the list?

Comment: for each Activity_ID there is Employee_count value, i want to sort Employee Count as top 10 sorting , i want to replace the value of Activity_ID that is equivalent to the least value in the sorting with Other value instead of the original value which is "C", so Yes i want to replace the last activity in the least with "Other" value

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `IF` statement in a new cell to replace text, such as:

```
=IF(A4="C", "Other", A4)
```

This will check and see if cell value A4 is "C", and if it is, it replaces it with the text "Other"; otherwise, it uses the contents of cell A4.

**EDIT**

Assuming that the `Employee_Count` values are in B1-B10, you can use this:

```
=IF(B1=LARGE($B$1:$B$10, 10), "Other", B1)
```

This function doesn't even require the data to be sorted; the `LARGE` function will find the 10th largest number in the series, and then the rest of the formula will compare against that.

Comment: i don't want to change the text if it is "C", i want to replace the text if the value is in the employee_count is the least value according to the top 10 sorting

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **Conditional Formatting** to replace text and NOT effect any formulas.  Simply go to the Rule's format where you will see **Number**, **Font**, **Border** and **Fill**.
 Go to the Number tab and select `CUSTOM`.  Then simply type where it says `TYPE`: what you want to say in QUOTES.

Example.. `"OTHER"`

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer? Because I tried your solution and it's not working...

Comment: Adding `;;;"Other"` instead of `"OTHER"` worked for me.

Comment: "OTHER" works only for numeric values. ;;;"Other" as mentioned above works for string values as well.
This only changes what can be seen visually though. The actual value (e.g. used for filtering) is still retained.