# Excel conditional replacement without a custom macro

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Is there a way to process the following column A to obtain column B using the Excel IF statement (or other but preferable NOT a custom macro, I would like to just have a formula) to obtain

```
A        B
X        X
_EMPTY   custom_row3
Y        Y
_EMPTY   custom_row5
Z        Z
```

In pseudo code

```
 FOREACH ROW
 IF (A!='_EMPTY) 
    B=A
ELSE 
    B='custom_row'+$ROWNUM$
END
```

I checked the related question [How to replace text of a cell based on condition in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399111/how-to-replace-text-of-a-cell-based-on-condition-in-excel), but it is not clear how to extend to this case which is a bit more complicated.

Comment: You could use a formula like `=IF(A1="", "custom_row"&ROW(), A1)` in B1 and fill down as necessary.

Comment: This works beautifully, just what I was looking for!  Note for other readers that the "," needs to be changed to a ";"

Comment: The semi-colon in place of a comma would be a system regional setting. Typically, North America and many other parts of the world use a comma as a *list separator* while certain parts of Europe and some others use a semi-colon. Excel reads this from the operating system's regional settings. As you provided no sample formula, I relied upon the more predominant one in use for my example. Glad you got sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use in B2

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"custom_row"&+ROW(),A2)
```

and copy downward.
Note a **VERY IMPORTANT** point. An **empty cell** behaves differently from a cell containing an **empty string**.
With reference to the figure, cells A3 and A6 are empty (blank), while cell A5 contains an empty string.

[image]

You may need to use

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A2),A2=""),"custom_row"&+ROW(),A2)
```

depending on the contents of your column A.
See [this relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27198611/2707864).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful as well as comment from Jeeped.  In fact I had replaced blanks by BLANK to avoid this problem, but your solution is much cleaner!